# MYSQL - how to a second unique string key?

Tags: mysql, string, key, unique

Here is my goods table.

```
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID                   | decimal(18,0) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| gkey                 | varchar(255)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| GOODS                | decimal(18,0) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
```

Column ID is auto-increment.
GOODS is the id of a goods category.
Here is the goods category table.

```
+-------+---------------------+
| ID    | NAME                |
+-------+---------------------+
| 1     | book                |
| 2     | phone               |
+-------+---------------------+
```

My question is in goods table I need the gkey is also an unique key with prefix-id(here id is started from 1.) Like BOOK-1,BOOK-2....PHONE-1,PHONE-2... when insert a new goods record into goods table.
Like that:

```
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID                 | GKEY          |GOODS | PRI | COUNTRY | Extra |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| 1                  | BOOK-1        | 1    | 10  |         |       |
| 2                  | PHONE-1       | 2    | 12  |         |       |
| 3                  | BOOK-2        | 1    | 13  |         |       |
| 4                  | BOOK-3        | 1    | 10  |         |       |
| 5                  | PHONE-2       | 2    | 10  |         |       |
| 6                  | PHONE-3       | 2    | 20  |         |       |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

How to get that GKEY in PHP+MYSQL?

thanks.

Comment: Any specific reason for this approach?

Comment: My really first question would be... why `decimal`, but why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNIQUE constraint. For more information check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp).

Comment: Adding a UNIQUE constraint is important, to prevent accidentally duplicating keys. But the constraint doesn't help you generate the keys in the first place so you need more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to be doing this at all. Instead, `good.gkey` should be a foreign key to `goods_category.id`. If the insertion order is important, you can add an `insert_date` date field to the goods table.

From there you can run all sorts of queries, with the added bonus of having referential integrity on your tables.

Comment: No reasons. This is the requirement from my boss. I just need to carry it out.
ps: Boss said this design is similar to Jira

Comment: There is already a foreign key from `goods.goods` to `good_categories.id`

Answer (score 0):

First you should do everything Database side. So no php. That would be my advice.

Then not having sequence in MySQL that what I would Suggest you :

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM GOODS
WHERE GKEY LIKE('BOOK-%')
```

Then you insert

```
INSERT INTO goods (id, "BOOK-" || SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(LENGTH(GKEY -1), LENGTH(GKEY))FROM GOODS WHERE GKEY LIKE('BOOK-%') + 1, ...)
```

This way you will always have the next number available.

Comment: That's not a good solution. If he deletes a record, `COUNT(id)` will no longer correspond to the last number inserted. I think he needs to normalize his database better, then everything else will be easier.

Comment: And I do agree. But maybe he has a client order that for any odd reason wants it this way. The design is terrible, but not having sequences in MySQL in order to answer its needs that the closes answer I can come with. Don't you agree ?

Comment: normalize database better? could you give me the details. I have no idea on it.

Comment: @acai : For me, you don't need your GKEY column because what does is represent ? The name of the GOODS ID column right next to it. So as AgentConundrum say just have Id, Categorie_Id, ..., ..., CreationDate, ModificationDate

Comment: @AgentConundrum: This is the requirement from my boss. I just need to carry it out. ps: Boss said this design is similar to Jira

Comment: @acai : Then try the peace of code I gave you, it should work !

Comment: @Spredzy: how about changing the COUNT(id) to MAX(gkey) in your peace of code?

Comment: @acail: You can't GKEY is varchar() so it doesn't make sense. More over you want a number. COUNT does the trick. Do you have a requiremetn from your boss telling you that when you delete an entry, next entry should replace it ? If you have book-1 book-2 book-3 then you delete book-2 what should be the next insert? Book-2 or Book-4?

Comment: @ I edited my answer. Now you get BOOK-3 just get the 3 (with substr) and add 1 so you know it will be 4.

Comment: @Spredzy: Thanks for your help and time. I will go to try your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but you need to be quite careful to make sure that two simultaneous inserts don't get given the same gkey. I'd design it with these two design points:

1. In the GoodsCategory table, have a **counter** which helps to generate the next gkey.
2. Use **locks** so that only one process can generate a new key at any one time.

Here's the details:
1. Add a couple of columns to the GoodsCategory table:

```
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID                   | TINYINT       | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| NAME                 | VARCHAR(80)   | NO   |     |         |       |
| KeyCode              | CHAR(5)       | NO   |     |         |       |
| NextID               | INT           | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The KeyCode has 'BOOK' or 'PHONE', and the NextID field stores an int which is used to generate the next key of that type i.e. if the table looks like this:

```
+----------------+------------+---------+--------+
| ID             | NAME       | KeyCode | NextID |
+----------------+------------+---------+--------+
| 1              | book       | BOOK    | 3      |
| 2              | phone      | PHONE   | 7      |
+----------------+------------+---------+--------+
```

Then the next time you add a book, it should be given gkey 'BOOK-3', and NextID is incremented to 4.

2: The **locking** will need to be done in a **stored routine**, because it involves multiple statements in a transaction and uses local variables too. The core of it should look something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT KeyCode, NextID INTO v_kc, v_int FROM GoodsCategory WHERE ID = 2 FOR UPDATE;
SET v_newgkey = v_kc + '-' + CAST(v_int AS CHAR);
INSERT INTO goods (gkey, goods, ...) VALUES (v_newgkey, 2, etc);
UPDATE GoodsCategory SET NextID = NextID + 1 WHERE ID = 2;
COMMIT;
```

The `FOR UPDATE` bit is crucial; have a look at the Usage Examples in the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) where it discusses how to use locks to generate an ID without interference from another process.